# how to clear browser hash history in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, navigation

I use [hashchange](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/document_domain/) plugin to imitate ajax navigation, i would like to create navigation throught folders, for example:

> **#root/ -> #root/folder -> #root/folder/subfolder -> #root/**

but when i go to last **#root/** in list i would like to clear previous navigation history

> **#root/folder -> #root/folder/subfolder**

Is any ability to do that?

Comment: History of hash URLs are handled by the browser just as normal browser history, and as far as I know that can't be altered by JavaScript. Such behavior would probably be confusing to users as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers with HTML5 support supports some manipulation via `window.history`. According to the [docs at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), the only supported actions are to *add* and *replace* history.

Removing browser history is thus **not supported**, but maybe [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history) can be used to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way in Javascript to navigate to a new page with leaving no history in the browser hash...
just use  `window.location.replace("any URL");`... see ur browser's page navigation buttons got disabled.. and also no 'Back' option will be available in right mouse click.. Hope this will help u :)