# clear browser cache and history via javascript and load latest js files

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to clear browser cache and history via javascript
I found some links like:-

[How to clear browser history oan clear cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671371/how-to-clear-browser-history-oan-clear-cache)

[how to clear browser hash history in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622460/how-to-clear-browser-hash-history-in-javascript)

but they do not properly described on how this can be achieved via javascript ( or jQuery)

I require this so that the user do not have to do a [Ctrl+F5] or manually clear cache
and the most recent version of javascript file is loaded in the browser.

The main aim is to load the latest javascript files every time the user visits the website. 
My application in ASP.NET MVC based and javascript files are included in .csHtml file.

Comment: A browser cache is maintained by the browser, not by JavaScript.

Comment: As @Bergi says, i don't think this is possible. you can however make the current cache invalid, which will cause to load you new updated files.

Comment: Use proper caching headers to begin with. Rename or add query strings to the files when they are updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are other ways to prevent a JavaScript file (or other files) from being cached.

Simply append some dummy parameters to the end of the url. For example -

```
http://www.yourCoolSite.com/resources/js/main.js?r=SOME_RANDOM_VALUE
```

You would optimally do this on the server side. In PHP, this would look something like this -

```
echo "http://www.yourCoolSite.com/resources/js/main.js?r=".time();
```

Using the `time()` function, we append the current epoch timestamp to the URL and therefore guarantee* that the file will appear different to the browser each time.

[<sup>* Until 2038 that is ;)</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: .htaccess may be cleaner, but this works when that isn't an option.

Comment: Or instead of SOME_RANDOM_VALUE you could append a hash of the file, this way, it does only get updated when there is something new.

Comment: @mrm - that's a great tip! You should add your own answer giving an example...

Comment: Perhaps slightly off-topic, but could you explain why it is only until 2038? Will the data type overflow in 2038 because too much seconds have past since 1/1/1970?

Comment: hi @MrMichael-can you please provide an example ( no server stuff though)

Comment: @116 - Pretty much :P [The 2038 "problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) is pretty much just another Y2K bug ;)

Comment: @Lix & Atur, currently in the office so i can't write such example at this moment, i will if i find some free time though. In the most simplest case you could define a shared constant which will be appended, such as a version. We do use a method similar but with ASP.NET on the server side but if this is not possible, you could look into the FileAPI which could do something like this in combination with an MD5 implementation for JS but FileAPI is not supported in older browsers as far as i know so it depends on your audience and if you are willing to go through all this. (and need such thing)

Comment: Would only go through that effort if your scripts are that heavy that you could not live without caching i guess or if it would be as simple as in ASP.NET (which has easy access to files on the server).

Comment: And it should work after 2038, because users cannot have a cached version of the js file before now. The only possible scenario (but _very_ improbable) is that a user visits the site, caches the js file and then, ***exactly*** 2^32 seconds later revisits the site.

Comment: @MrMichael, the scripts are indeed heavy. Loading them in ASP.NET MVC app. The app is currently in development and I want to have users the latest javascript file ( as these files are updated daily)

Comment: I tried this as well as `.htacess` option but somehow it doesn't... is there a full-proof solution ?

Answer (score 17):

call `window.location.reload(true)` for a `ctrl+F5` from script. :)

Comment: But does that _really_ ignore cached versions of the files of that location?

Comment: yes it does indeed. check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536691%28VS.85%29.aspx